# How to draw text in a bitmap?

Tags: android

How can I draw text on a bitmap? I made this:

```
    float width = Converter.convertDpToPixel(250, context);
    float height = Converter.convertDpToPixel(40, context);
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width + 1, (int)height+1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface tanger = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Tangerine_Bold.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(tanger);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(55);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    myCanvas.drawText(quote, 16, 60, paint);
    return myBitmap;
```

but only display a part of the text and I don´t know why.
Thank you

Comment: You have a 250x40 bitmap and you are drawing text centered at 16x60...

Comment: Yes, that´s the problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Bitmap is `40px` in `height`, while your text is drawn starting from `60px` below the top of your bitmap. Since your `textSize` is `55` part of it is still visible. You'll probably want to increase the height of your `Bitmap`.

Comment: Increasing size of bitmap will streatch image what he want is increasing size of canvas. Am I right?